# 'metadata' is an invalid connection string attribute in ASP.Net MVC using Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

In my controller I have a `JsonResult` function called by a Javascript that's called by a button in `View`. this will save input from textbox to database table. But in it's first line of code (connecting to Oracle), it's alread having an error:

```
using (var con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBEntities"].ConnectionString))
```

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: 'metadata' is an invalid connection string
>   attribute

Here's my auto-generated connectionString in web.config:

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=DBDEV;PASSWORD=db;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

What seems to be the problem? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle ODP.Net With Entity Framework 6 - Entity framework database compatible provider could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656519/oracle-odp-net-with-entity-framework-6-entity-framework-database-compatible-pr)

Comment: I believe the link you posted is not the same with mine. They don't even mention there the metadata connectionstring

Comment: Not exact duplicate but those are the steps you need to follow to connect with Oracle DB in EF code first approach. It talks about how connection string should exactly look like when using Oracle DB with EF.

Comment: I tried the solution but it didn't fix my problem. Same `System.ArgumentException` error

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and resolved it using this post: 
[Keyword Not Supported: Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183777/keyword-not-supported-metadata)

The trick is because it is Oracle you need to change your string to something like this:

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DBDEV;PASSWORD=db;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=db&quot;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

I know this post is super old, but hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Lose the end quote. It's only the silly EF which uses it.

<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DBDEV;PASSWORD=db;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=userId" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />