# entity data model wizard crashes with oracle connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, visual-studio, entity-framework, odp.net

When trying to create model with entity frameowrk database first method, the entity data model wizard crashes. I am trying to connect to oracle database. 
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version :19.6
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework version : 19.6
ODAC Version 18.3
Entity Framework Version:6.0
Image has been attached for refernce. Process after process mentioned in the image is  crashing.[image]

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version? It seems similar to [entity-data-model-wizard-crash-with-oracle-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083706/entity-data-model-wizard-crash-with-oracle-connection)

Comment: visual studio 2017. I have tried the answer mentioned in the given link. it didn't work for me.

Comment: Your major  version of ODP.NET needs to match the major version of Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. You are using ODP.NET 19.6, but the latest version of ODT is 18.3. You'll need to downgrade to ODP.NET 18 or wait for ODT 19 to come out.

Answer (score 0):

The rule still applies today. ODT Version must match the version of oracle.manageddataaccess and oracle.manageddataacess.entityframework obtained by nuget. It is very tempting to update thru nuget to a later version, but ODT will than crash.
I often have a parallel project to generate my code first model and than copy the files to my model project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5, NET.Framework 4.6.1

It was happening the same error in my project, I was tryng to use EnityFramework and Oracle Manage Data Access most recent versions. When downgrade the fallowing versions. It start to working without any errors

Versions that worked for me:

- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- Oracle.ManagedDataAcces 12.2.20230118
- Oracle.ManagedDataAcces.EntityFramework 12.2.20230118

The EntityFramework 6.4.4 worked to... But every time I try to scaffold a Entity from the database, It autommatically downgrade to version 6.1.3